# How do I sample the number of records in another table?

Tags: sql, teradata, sample

I have code where I'm sampling 50,000 random records. I.e.,

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  SAMPLE 50000;
```

That works. However, what I really want to do is sample the number of records that are in a different table. I.e.,

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  SAMPLE count(*) FROM Table2;
```

I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL for it to be random. Does it need to be random or can you have an ordering?

Comment: Interesting. It has to be random.

Comment: True randomness definitely complicates it. I may have spoke to soon with dynamic SQL (that would certainly work) but there probably is a route that avoids it. What I should have said is that you'll need dynamic SQL to write it as "WHERE SAMPLE <= :Your_Parameter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not randomized like sample, so bear that in mind. But there also won't be an obvious pattern, I believe it's determined by disk location (don't quote me on that).

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM Table1
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER
             ( PARTITION BY 1
                   ORDER BY 1
             ) <= 
             ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM Table2
             );
```

Better way

```
    SELECT TMP.* -- Or list the columns you want with "rnd" 
      FROM ( SELECT RANDOM(-10000000,10000000) rnd,
                    T1.*
               FROM Table1 T1
           ) TMP
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER
             ( ORDER BY rnd
             ) <= 
             ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM Table2
             );
```

Comment: Hmmm. I get an error: "Teradata exception: [Teradata Database][3706] Syntax error: expected something between an integer and ')'

Comment: Here's the exact code I'm running that gives me the error: SELECT * 
FROM table1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER
( PARTITION BY 1) <= 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2);

Comment: Great! Also, take a look at the alternative I added. Depending on the size of the data you might have to up the constants if you are working with a large data set. This will be as "random" as generated numbers can be.

Comment: Ok ok. Is the first one random at all? Like, is it just taking the first records from table1?

Comment: @JacobCurtis Not random at all, but you wouldn't be able to determine the pattern by looking at it. It would also return the same result every time it's run. The second approach is categorically better, both from performance (should be) and if you are assuming randomness in the statistical sense.

Comment: #1 is not really random and will cause severe skew for a large table because all rows will be processed by a single AMP. Most efficient will be a Stored Procedure calculating the count first and then submiting Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT TOP 50000 * FROM Table1 ORDER BY NEWID()